# Pandas: Add new column based on comparison of two DFs

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes that I am wanting to compare one to the other and add a 'True/False' to a new column in the first based on the comparison.

My data resembles:

DF1:

```
        cat  sub-cat    low       high
3       3        1      208       223
4       3        1      224       350
8       4        1      223       244
9       4        1      245       350
13      5        1      232       252
14      5        1      253       350
```

DF2:

```
      Cat   Sub-Cat   Rating
0     5      1           246
1     5      2           239
2     8      1           203
3     8      2           218
4     K      1           149
5     K      2           165
6     K      1           171
7     K      2           185
8     K      1           157
9     K      2           171
```

Desired result would be for DF2 to have an additional column with a True or False depending on if, based on the cat and sub-cat, that the rating is between the low.min() and high.max() or Null if no matches found to compare.

Have been running rounds with this for far too long with no results to speak of.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Update:

First row would look something like:

```
      Cat   Sub-Cat   Rating  In-Spec
0     5      1           246    True
```

As it falls within the min low and the max high.

Example: There are two rows in DF1 for cat = 5 and sub-cat = 2. I need to get the minimum low and the maximum high from those 2 rows and then check if the rating from row 0 in DF2 falls within the minimum low and maximum high from the two matching rows in DF1

Comment: Please show us what you think the result should be for say the first row.

Comment: Of course, my apologies.

Comment: Which rows do you want to evaluate/compare? The ones with the same index or the ones with an identical cat & subcat ?

Comment: Cat/Subcat is desired comparison. Index is not important

Comment: do you mean that the rating is between the row's low and the row's high?  Because you said `low.min()`, that implies to me that you meant the minimum for the whole column.  Which did you mean?

Comment: As shown in DF1 for cat = 5/sub-cat = 1 there are 2 rows matching.

I need to check if  row 0's rating in DF2 falls within the minimum low and maximum high for those 2 matching rows in DF1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` post `groupby.agg`

```
d2 = DF2.join(
    DF1.groupby(
        ['cat', 'sub-cat']
    ).agg(dict(low='min', high='max')),
    on=['Cat', 'Sub-Cat']
)
d2

  Cat  Sub-Cat  Rating   high    low
0   5        1     246  350.0  232.0
1   5        2     239    NaN    NaN
2   8        1     203    NaN    NaN
3   8        2     218    NaN    NaN
4   K        1     149    NaN    NaN
5   K        2     165    NaN    NaN
6   K        1     171    NaN    NaN
7   K        2     185    NaN    NaN
8   K        1     157    NaN    NaN
9   K        2     171    NaN    NaN
```

---

***assign with `.loc`***

```
DF2.loc[d2.eval('low <= Rating <= high'), 'In-Spec'] = True
DF2

  Cat  Sub-Cat  Rating In-Spec
0   5        1     246    True
1   5        2     239     NaN
2   8        1     203     NaN
3   8        2     218     NaN
4   K        1     149     NaN
5   K        2     165     NaN
6   K        1     171     NaN
7   K        2     185     NaN
8   K        1     157     NaN
9   K        2     171     NaN
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new column based on a boolean expression would involve something along the lines of:

```
temp = boolean code involving inequality
df2['new column name'] = temp
```

However I'm not sure I understand, the first row in your DF2 table for instance, has a rating of 246, which means it's true for row 13 of DF1, but false for row 14. What would you like it to return?

Comment: Once a true is found against cat/subcat I need to ensure that rating falls within the minimum and maximum of the corresponding rows in DF1. The data comes to me in pairs like that with row 13 and 14, but I need to compare them to lowest low and highest high.

Comment: You can use groupby on DF1 with df1.groupby(['cat,'sub-cat'])[low].min()[high].max() to create a new dataframe with the max and min values for each pair of cat and sub-cat

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
df2['In-Spec'] = 'False'
df2['In-Spec'][(df2['Rating'] > df1['low']) & (df2['Rating'] < df1['high'])] = 'True'
```

But which rows should be compared with each others? Do you want them to compare by their index or by their cat & subcat names?